# How to add images containing attributes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, imagery

I am new to QGIS.  I know how to add vector and raster files into QGIS.  I have some satellite images taken at different times of the same location.  In addition, there are some annotation data associated with each file.

I also find the eVis plugin can integrate images on locations of any vector file.  The eVis display window, however, is small and cannot be zoomed in/out.  Does anyone know any way that I can add my images into QGIS on the "Map View" area and be able to edit my attribute information for each image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create some sort of index vector of all your images then add the attribute information in the attribute table.

If eVis is too limiting for you.  You can open other image browser/application using the `Actions Tab`.

Comment: Appreciate!  That is what I am doing.  But I still wonder whether there are other solutions.